# NGINX - Client-side authentication continues working even after USB token has been removed

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have a website running on apache2, on which the client is authenticated by a SSL certificate stored on a USB drive. Between the client and the web server, there is a NGINX reverse proxy.

Authentication works as follows:

1) On the reverse proxy, I set two custom headers containing the client certificate serial and DN:

```
proxy_set_header x-secondary-serial $ssl_client_serial;
proxy_set_header x-secondary-dn $ssl_client_s_dn;
```

2) On the web server, some PHP code checks that the serial is in a list of allowed certificates. I've checked with the developer that the serial is verified on every page.

Now, my problem is that when I unplug the USB drive and continue to navigate, I am still authenticated. It only seems to timeout after 10 minutes of complete inactivity (if I launch a request before those 10 minutes, I have to wait another 10 minutes for the timeout to occur and the page to ask me to insert the key).

I have checked the logs and for every request after the removal of the USB drive, the headers (*x-secondary-serial* and *x-secondary-dn*) are still populated with the correct values. So, I thought about cache and tried to add this to my nginx server block (with no success):

```
ssl_session_cache off;
```

I also tried to shorten timeout duration (no success and anyway, I don't really like this solution):

```
ssl_session_timeout 1m;
```

I would like to enforce a systematic verification of the client certificate on every single request (preferably on the reverse proxy, since this is the server I have most control over).

Here is the complete server block:

```
    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.org;

        ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/example.org.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/private/example.org.key;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache off;
        #ssl_session_timeout 1m;

        # SSL client authentication
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/CertEurope_fullchain.crt;
        ssl_verify_depth 2;
        ssl_verify_client optional;

        client_max_body_size 2048m;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header SSL_PROTOCOL $ssl_protocol;

                proxy_set_header x-secondary-serial $ssl_client_serial;
                proxy_set_header x-secondary-dn $ssl_client_s_dn;

                proxy_read_timeout           90;

                access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.log;
                error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.log;

                proxy_pass         https://10.13.1.1/;
        }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this issue?

Regards

Comment: How are you getting the certificate from the USB stick to the server? Are you using a web browser or something else? Please don't leave out any details.

Comment: A connection can have multiple requests in it. The TLS handshake (which needs  the client certificate) is only done at the beginning of the connection. Try with disabling HTTP keep-alive by setting `keepalive_timeout 0;`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The e-manual of the USB stick makes you add the USB stick to Firefox Device Manager as a "security device". The user reporting the problem did that, but he then uses Chrome to access the website. I don't really understand how Chrome can use the USB stick declared into Firefox but it seems to work (perhaps the Device Manager used by Firefox is system-wide?). Anyway, I redid the test on Firefox, and discovered that the behaviour is normal: when we unplug the USB stick, the next request fails (as should be). The "10-minutes delay problem" occurs in Chrome only.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the suggestion, it may actually work. What is the impact and possible side-effects of disabling HTTP keep-alive?

Comment: It will take longer to load every page, possibly noticeably longer. I would only do that for long enough to determine whether that is actually what is happening.